# encoding.decoding regional characters and showing correctly in html

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I set label in my HTML Form by jquery based on Model Data:

```
$("#someField").val('@Model.City');
```

If i have in Model.City regional characters e.g. Malmö
i see it like  'Malm & # 246; ( without spaces )

How to encode this ?

Thnx

Comment: How do you retrieve your data? With jquery (`WebMethod`) or as a `View` from the controller?

Comment: View from Controller

Comment: Okay, hmmmmmm. What I ask myself: Why don't you set the value of the element with the id `#someField` directly as an attribute but instead via jQuery?